# Identifying a connection terminal specification from photo

Tags: connector, soldering, pins, wire-terminals, terminal-block

I'm having difficulty identifying the 12 pin connection as seen in the photos below.

It appears to be a JST, but upon purchasing some 12 pin JSTs, they do not fit and are too big.

Is there a way to identify which connection type this is?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's the pitch, 2mm? What are "some 12 pin JST" which didn't fit?

Comment: @Lundin the hole/slot for each pin on my amazon sourced 12 pin jst connector blocks were too big aside from the pitch not aligning.

Comment: Yes I got that much but if we knew the JST partno we could rule that out. Again, what is the pitch? And avoid buying electronics components from Amazon, buy from a serious component vendor.

Comment: @Lundin I don't know the part number/serial. Using the picture with ruler, there is a 1mm spacing between each of the 12 pins. The overall JST housing is 20mm

Comment: I asked what cable part you bought which didn't fit. At least you ought to know that much...? Anyway, I think Davide has found the answer, so it's a Molex and not JST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My [Identiconn utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=lo_prof_1r_w2b_conn_1p2&s=PicoBlade%20(3w)) identified it as a Molex Picoblade, 3-wall header.

https://www.molex.com/en-us/products/connectors/wire-to-board-connectors/picoblade-connectors

[image]

{[Source - Digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0533984012/15622925)}

EDIT - Plug housing: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0510211200/242852?

Comment: What a brilliant tool, thanks for creating it and also posting it here for use. It wasn't a JST after all

Comment: do you know what the opposite connecting connector is called? The part with the wires used to slot in the housing? The picture above is known as the header

Comment: "do you know what the opposite connecting connector is called?" - The mate is called a "plug". I added a link to in in my answer.

Comment: @davidandrea do the plugs not come with wires? Seems very hard to locate a wire assembly version

Comment: "do the plugs not come with wires? " -- No, they don't, not from Molex. However, Chinese companies assemble  terminated wires on certain plugs. Look in AliExpress, Amazon, and eBay.

Comment: You are a legend my son, you just may not know it! Cheers

Comment: "my son" -- I am 65 years old.